# ¿Porque no me toma los datos de la consola?

Tags: vscode, dart

estoy empezando aver Dart en la escuela y para una tarea me pidieron hacer una tienda de cualquier producto con maps, a la hora de pedir la opcion de los tipos de helados e ingresar el dato no me reliza ninguna accion, sea con mi codigo u otro que me pida ingresar datos, habra algun error con la isntalación de dart?? no se si hay error con la isntalación de SDK la verdad no estoy muy enterado ya que al inicio instale android studio y flutter pero tuve problema con la SDK, asi que mi porfesor me dijo que mejor trabajara con VSCode, pero no estoy usando flutter si no Dart y ejecutando en consola asi que no se si tenga algo que ver.

```
`import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  // Definir los mapas
  Map<String, dynamic> napolitano = {
    'Nombre': "Helado Napolitano",
    'Marca': "Holanda",
    'Litros': 1.89,
    'Precio': 125.0,
    'Stock': 100,
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> vainilla = {
    'Nombre': "Helado Vainilla",
    'Marca': "Holanda",
    'Litros': 1.89,
    'Precio': 103.0,
    'Stock': 100,
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> oreo = {
    'Nombre': "Helado Oreo",
    'Marca': "Holanda",
    'Litros': 1.89,
    'Precio': 183.0,
    'Stock': 100,
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> napolitanoZero = {
    'Nombre': "Helado Napolitano Zero Azúcar",
    'Marca': "Holanda",
    'Litros': 1.0,
    'Precio': 80.0,
    'Stock': 100,
  };

    introducir el código aquí

  // Mostrar opciones al usuario
  print('Tienda Don Juan Polla');
  print("Sabor de helado a comprar");
  print(" 1) Napolitano      ${napolitano['Litros']}lts. // \$${napolitano['Precio']}");
  print(" 2) Vainilla        ${vainilla['Litros']}lts. // \$${vainilla['Precio']}");
  print(" 3) Oreo            ${oreo['Litros']}lts. // \$${oreo['Precio']}");
  print(" 4) Napolitano Zero ${napolitanoZero['Litros']}lts. // \$${napolitanoZero['Precio']}");

  // Obtener la opción del usuario
  String? input;

  try {
    input = stdin.readLineSync();
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error al leer la entrada del usuario: $e");
    exit(1);
  }

  // Realizar acciones según la opción seleccionada
  switch (input) {
    case '1':
      print("Cantidad disponible: ${napolitano['Stock']}");
      break;
    case '2':
      print("Cantidad disponible: ${vainilla['Stock']}");
      break;
    case '3':
      print("Cantidad disponible: ${oreo['Stock']}");
      break;
    case '4':
      print("Cantidad disponible: ${napolitanoZero['Stock']}");
      break;
    default:
      print("Opción no válida");
      break;
  }

}
`
```

Aqui dejo la consola [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es extraño porque _creería_ que tu código sí funciona testeándolo en [este sitio](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_dart_online.php).

Comment: Y no entiendo qué tiene que ver VSCode en la ecuación...

Comment: Normalmente para hacer un input debes usar la solapa "Terminal"